# require nokogiri: Load Error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, html-parsing, nokogiri, require

I'm new to Ruby and I was looking around for libraries to parse html and found Nokogiri. The problem I'm having is if I fire up IRB and type `require 'nokogiri'`, it works fine and prints out `true`. But if I include that as a part of my `.rb` file and execute it with `ruby <scriptname>`, it gives me a `LoadError: no such file to load` message.

My Ruby version is 1.8.7 if I type `ruby --version` in the terminal.

Comment: Do you need to `require 'rubygems'` before requiring Nokogiri in your script?  IRB could be loading rubygems by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding

```
require 'rubygems'
```

to the .rb file.

In Ruby 1.9+ rubygem is loaded automatically and not needed. Although there is debate whether that line is required pre 1.9.

Nevertheless, give it a shot.

Comment: There's no debate; it is required for 1.8.7 but not for 1.9.